# Travis CI build fails on pre-TCI pull requests: "Could not find .travis.yml"

Tags: git, travis-ci

I recently added automatic testing of pull requests via Travis CI to an open source Android project on GitHub. The main branch passes all build tests. I went through some outstanding pull requests, closing and opening them to force builds. The build fails on all pull requests from before I added the .travis.yml file with the following error in the logs:

> "Could not find .travis.yml, using standard configuration."

It then builds with rake and fails. The Travis CI [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests) say

> Rather than test the commits from the branches the pull request is
>   sent from, we test the merge between the origin and the upstream
>   branch.

If it's merging with the upstream master branch, though, .travis.yml should be included in the build. Is there a solution besides updating all the pull requests?

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has the same issue, I was ultimately unable to resolve it from within Travis-CI. I had to ask contributors to go into the feature branch corresponding to the PR, pull the upstream master to bring the .travis.yml file down, then push to update the PR.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe .travis.yml is not in the repository. Add it with

`git add .travis.yml`

If you make:

`git add *`

You could experience that error

Comment: This was resolved a few months ago, but thanks for taking a look. While .travis.yml was in the repository, it wasn't in the forks of the contributors submitting the PRs. I asked the contributors to pull from the upstream repo and resubmit their PRs, and the issue was resolved. Ultimately it only affected the PRs that were outstanding when I added Travis to the project.